# Difference between delayed functions and normal functions in Dask

Tags: python, dask

I created an `Aggregation` object to emulate pandas `first` operation and it was working fine with dask dataframes, but when used inside a delayed function, it gives a pandas error saying `'Aggregation' object is not callable`, whereas in this case using just pandas first works. On later inspection, I discovered that my manipulation function receiving a Dask DataFrame was receiving a normal pandas DataFrame when adding the `@delayed` decorator.

Clearly there's something I didn't understand on how dask and distributed work with the underlying data structures and I don't see this difference explained in https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manage-computation.html. Would you please explain the low level details of these differences, or point me out to some documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dask.dataframe.Aggregation objects are only intended for dask dataframes, not for any other kind of dask object.

Dask delayed generally operates on normal in-memory data.  There is no sophistication or automation applied at all.  All of the work to design custom algorithms is entirely on you when using dask.delayed.